# Can we describe Gibbs Free Energy in terms of microstates?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I am reading statistical physics currently, and I'm on the topic "Grand Canonical ensemble-condition of equilibrium". They've introduced a new term "Chemical Potential" which is Gibbs free energy per particle of a system.
Q1. How to relate Number of microstates with Gibbs Free energy?
Q2. How do we say that chemical potential is gibbs free energy per particle?@@

Answer (score 1):

The Gibbs energy $G$ is acquired by starting from the internal energy
$$U(S,V,N)= TS -PV+\mu N$$
$$dU = TdS - PdV + \mu dN$$
and performing two successive Legendre transformations - first to the Helmholtz energy
$$F = U - TS$$
$$dF = dU-TdS -SdT = -SdT - PdV+\mu dN$$
then to the Gibbs energy
$$G = F+PV$$
$$dG = dF +PdV + VdP = -SdT +VdP +\mu dN$$
From this one can see that the entropy is related to the Gibbs energy via
$$S = -\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}\right)_{P,N}$$
and from there $\Omega = \exp(S/k_B)$ is the number of accessible microstates in the equilibrium configuration at a particular $(T,P,N)$. Following the above Legendre transformations, we see that $G=\mu N$, so $\mu = G/N$ is the average Gibbs energy per particle.

Comment: @DheerajChoudhary Yes, I wrote that in my second-to-last sentence. $\Omega = \exp(S/k_B)$.